# Adding keys and values to an empty dictionary using for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have 3 lists and an empty dictionary:

```
dict = {}

name = ['Bob', 'Amy', 'Jack']
gender = ['Male', 'Female', 'Male']
car = ['kia', 'ford', 'audi']
country = ['UK', 'US', 'Australia']
```

Can I use a for loop in order to create dictionary entries? So ideally I'd end up with:

```
dict = {'Bob': {'gender':'Male', 'car':'kia', 'country':'UK'},
        'Amy': {'gender':'Female', 'car':'ford', 'country':'US'},
        'Jack': {'gender':'Male', 'car':'audi', 'country':'Australia'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) and a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
dct = {n: {'gender': g, 'car': k, 'country': c}
       for n, g, k, c in zip(name, gender, car, country)}
```

---

As a side note, avoid naming your variables using builtin names in Python, such as `dict` (I am using `dct` instead, but a better name could be `people` or, even better, something you can think of that fits your actual use case).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`dict comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
name = ['Bob', 'Amy', 'Jack']
gender = ['Male', 'Female', 'Male']
car = ['kia', 'ford', 'audi']
country = ['UK', 'US', 'Australia']

db = {name: dict(zip(['gender', 'car', 'country'], rest)) 
            for name, *rest 
            in zip(name, gender, car, country)
     }
print(db)
```

Output:

```
{'Bob': {'gender': 'Male', 'car': 'kia', 'country': 'UK'},
 'Amy': {'gender': 'Female', 'car': 'ford', 'country': 'US'},
 'Jack': {'gender': 'Male', 'car': 'audi', 'country': 'Australia'}}
```

Unpacked it looks like:

```
for data in zip(name, gender, car, country):
    n, g, ca, co = data
    db[n] = {
        'gender' : g,
        'car'    : ca,
        'country': co
    }
```

If we see, what the `zip` returns:

```
>>> for data in zip(name, gender, car, country):
        print(data)

('Bob', 'Male', 'kia', 'UK')
('Amy', 'Female', 'ford', 'US')
('Jack', 'Male', 'audi', 'Australia')
```

Now, we can unpack these tuples (see [`iterable unpacking`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
>>> n, g, ca, co = ('Bob', 'Male', 'kia', 'UK')
>>> n
'Bob'
>>> g
'Male'
>>> ca
'kia'
>>> co
'UK'

# Or we can take the name separately (as shown in dict comprehension):
>>> name, *rest = ('Bob', 'Male', 'kia', 'UK')
>>> name
'Bob'
>>> rest
['Male', 'kia', 'UK']
```

Now, let's take a look at how we can make a dict by calling [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
>>> dict(a=2, b=3)
{'a': 2, 'b': 3}

# or if we have a bunch of tuples, for example:
>>> items = [('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
>>> dict(items)
{'a': 2, 'b': 3}

# so it is evident, it takes key-value pairs, so:
# and we supply, keys = ['gender', 'car', 'country']
# if we have, rest = ['Male', 'kia', 'UK'], which are the values
# we can zip them together to get key value pairs:
>>> list(zip(keys, rest))
[('gender', 'Male'), ('car', 'kia'), ('country', 'UK')]
# now we can call dict
>>> dict(zip(keys, rest))
{'gender': 'Male', 'car': 'kia', 'country': 'UK'}
```